# EXCEL Trying to copy row to new created workbook getting Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

I have a large file with rows of account data.  Each account has a unique number of rows.  I want to create a new file for each account, move those account records to the new file and save that new file. The account number is in Column A.  I have the logic to loop through the code and determine when the account number changes.  My problem is I can't write any records to my newly created file.  I get a run-time error'9': Subscript out of range.

```
Private Sub createfiles()

Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim fileName As String
Dim initial As Integer

initial = 1

fileName = "O:\Paula\Z Install History\Testing\" & Cells(initial + 1, 1).Text & ".xlsx"

Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add

With Newbook
    .Title = "Installment Trans History"
    .Subject = "legal Request"
    .SaveAs fileName:=fileName
End With

' open new workbook and copy first title row

 Workbooks.Open (fileName)

  Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy _
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
  ' set row value in new file
  writerow = 2
For current = 2 To Lastrow

 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(current, 1) <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(current + 1, 1) Then

      ' Write the current record and close file

      Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(current, 1).Copy _
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(writerow, 1)

      Workbooks(fileName).Close SaveChanges:=True

      writerow = 1

      ' create a new file  and write column header row

      fileName = "O:\Paula\Z Install History\Testing\" & Cells(current + 1, 1).Text & ".xlsx"
         Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
            With Newbook
                 .Title = "Installment Trans History"
                 .Subject = "legal Request"
                 .SaveAs fileName:=fileName

          End With
          Workbooks.Open (fileName)

          Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy _
                Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Range(writerow, 1).Select
          writerow = writerow + 1

     Else
      ' Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Copy _
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

       Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Copy _
                  Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(writerow, 1)

       writerow = writerow + 1



 End If
Next

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

My code will create the file as the first account name, however when I try to write to that newly created file, I get the subscript out of range error message.  My first time through, I'm trying to write the column headers, after that I'm trying to write the row I'm processing.

Comment: You've used `.Rows(current, 1)` - which isn't how you use `.Rows` - it requires only the one parameter. Elsewhere, you've used `.Rows(1).EntireRow` which is probably what you should be using.

Comment: It occurs on the first write, I changed it as suggested, but still does not work....      Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows("1").EntireRow.Copy _
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(1).EntireRow

Comment: Your first `Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").....EntireRow.Copy` line ends with a destination of `.Range("A1").Select` - you need to remove the `.Select` for that line to work. (note: I can see this twice in your code)

Comment: Sorry I did not highlight it.  This is my first question.  I'm new to VBA coding....

Comment: Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows("1").EntireRow.Copy _
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")   Still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go at re-writing your code, creating objects to refer to a 'source sheet' and a 'destination sheet' to help make the code more readable. I've kept as much of your process in there as possible so you should recognise most of it.

```
Private Sub createfiles_TestMe()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim writeRow As Long
Dim Current As Long
Dim fileName As String
Dim initial As Integer
Dim DestBook As Workbook
Dim SourceBook As Workbook
Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet

Set SourceBook = Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm")
Set SourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

LastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

initial = 1

fileName = "O:\Paula\Z Install History\Testing\" & Cells(initial + 1, 1).Text & ".xlsx"

Set DestBook = Workbooks.Add

With DestBook
    .Title = "Installment Trans History"
    .Subject = "legal Request"
    .SaveAs fileName:=fileName
    Set DestSheet = .Worksheets("sheet1")
End With

Set DestSheet = DestBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

' Copy header across

 SourceSheet.Rows(1).Copy DestSheet.Rows(1)

' set row value in new file

writeRow = 2

For Current = 2 To LastRow

    If SourceSheet.Cells(Current, 1) <> SourceSheet.Cells(Current + 1, 1) Then

        ' Write the current record and close file

        SourceSheet.Rows(Current).Copy DestSheet.Rows(writeRow)

        DestBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

        writeRow = 1

        ' create a new file  and write column header row
        If Current < LastRow Then

            fileName = "O:\Paula\Z Install History\Testing\" & Cells(Current + 1, 1).Text & ".xlsx"

            Set DestBook = Workbooks.Add

            With DestBook
                .Title = "Installment Trans History"
                .Subject = "legal Request"
                .SaveAs fileName:=fileName
                Set DestSheet = .Worksheets("sheet1")
            End With

            SourceSheet.Rows(1).Copy DestSheet.Rows(1)
        End If
    Else

        SourceSheet.Rows(Current).Copy DestSheet.Rows(writeRow)

    End If

    writeRow = writeRow + 1
Next

SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I've tested the above on a simple table, based on what I think you're trying to do - but as we can't see your data it's difficult to know if this will work.

Comment: You are amazing!  This worked perfectly.  It created all the files I needed and moved the records properly.   Do you have any recommendations for references/training on VBA programming?  I'm new to coding with VBA, but I'm anxious to learn.  Thanks you so much for you help!

Comment: Sorry, I just picked things up by tinkering in Excel, extensive use of Google (which brought me to this site) and recording macros - probably what you're doing right now. Some people learn best, this way. You have used the site properly, having a go yourself and getting very close - just needing a point here and there to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  My boss is already asking me to make a few changes and we are using the macro.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing:

`Workbooks("25 acct record.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows("1").EntireRow.Copy _
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select`

Note that I wrote the row number between quotatiton marks: .Rows("1")

Comment: Hi Pedro, can you explain *why* you've wrapped the row number in quotes?

Comment: Actually, it's the way I always do so I do not have further explanation other than that.

Comment: The string literal argument is silently converted to a `Long` value. Don't do this.

Comment: Hi @pedro_galher , first and foremost, this is a learning site - somewhere to share knowledge with the community. If you have a solution to a query, providing it is one thing but it's always a good idea to explain the solution to help them understand what you've provided. If you're not sure why something works then there is no harm in adding that to your answer and that invites others to explain it. In this case though, while your answer might work (for that line), the quotes make no difference at all. Also, as you'll learn as you use this site, we always advise against use of `.Select`.